How to get tar contents out of a hexa representation
I make RESTAPI call to an endpoint and I expect to receive .tar contents. But what I received is
<Buffer 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 13 01 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 01......

The method connectForTar shows how I receive the response and how I handle it.
Is it possible to convert that hexa representation to tar? I want to get the tar contents out of it, please.
code:
connectForTar(options, body, onResult) {
    const resCallback = (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
            console.error(errorTag,"Did not get an OK from the server. Code:",response.statusCode);
            console.error(errorTag,"Did not get an OK from the server. Msg:",response.statusMessage);
            onResult(response.statusCode, null);
            response.resume();
            return;
        }
        
        let data = [];
        let buffer = null;
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data.push(chunk);
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
            buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
            console.info({msg:infoTag +' response ended',contents:buffer});
            onResult(response.statusCode, buffer, null);                
        });
    }
    
    const req = https.request(options, resCallback);
    req.write(JSON.stringify(body));
    req.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(errorTag + "problem with request.e.:", err);
        console.error(errorTag + "problem with request.e.stack:", err.stack);
    });
    req.end();
}

tar contents


You mean something like fs.writeFileSync('./output.tar', buffer);

@mplungjan thanks, now using the code you provided, the output.tar got written to the disk, but it is not recognize as a valid archive, i can not unzip it

Can you save the content from the site you use the API on and compare bytewise to what you get? Can you paste the actual first 100 bytes of what you get - perhaps we can find a way to recognise it

Now that you have the bytes on your file system, use file output.tar (if you're on an UNIX system) to see what your machine thinks is in the file.

@AKX please have  a look at the modification i added to the question, i posted an image containing the what the .tar file contains

@mplungjan please have  a look at the modification i added to the question, i posted an image containing the what the .tar file contains

Whoever's told you you're getting a TAR file has misled you.
Based on the first bytes, MM<nul>* (4D 4D 00 2A in hexadecimal), you have a big-endian TIFF file, not a TAR file. (In other words, it's hard to get TAR contents out of those bytes, since they're evidently not a TAR.)
Given that the file also mentions Mercator, I would wager it's a GeoTIFF file.

(Looking at your earlier related question, you're doing RequestNDVIAsTimeSeriesInGeoTIFF... so it's little wonder you're getting a GeoTIFF.)

strange, because before i make restapi call programmatically, i test it on what so called request builderhttps://apps.sentinel-hub.com/requests-builder/
and according to the json request i post to the request builder i receive a .tar file!! however, i changed the extenetion from .tar to .tiff, but also the file can not be opened/accessed

What does "can not be opened/accessed" mean? Clearly the file could be opened and accessed since you showed us its contents above.

Anyway, I'm pretty sure your code is not doing the same request that you've tried on that request builder then, but since you're not showing us the part that builds options, I can just guess.

thanks, your answer helped me to spot where the bug is.
