How to extract and write contents of tar file to disk
I make RESTAPI call to an endpoint, and I receive the response in the following format
<Buffer 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 13 01 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 01......

what i am receiving is tar file contents, and it should contain six files.
As shown in the below posted code, i used the following line of code to write the hexa representation to the disk as .tar files.
When i try to access the output.tar, i find it contains only one file, while there should be six.
am I doing something wrong please?
code:
connectForTar(options, body, onResult) {
    const resCallback = (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
            onResult(response.statusCode, null, ({msg:'Did not get an OK from the 
            server',statusMessage:statusMessage}));
            response.resume();
            return;
        }
        
        let data = [];
        let buffer = null;
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data.push(chunk);
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
            buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
            onResult(response.statusCode, buffer, null);

            fs.writeFileSync('C:\\..\\.....\\..\\..\\..\\webservices\\projects\\..\\controller\\IO\\tars
           \\output.tar', buffer);
        });
    }
}


Looks very much like your previous question but I guess it is not a dupe. Do you actually get a tar file and can it be extracted to just one file?

But, you're still getting a TIFF file, aren't you? it's the same data as in your last two questions, one of which you ACCEPTED an answer telling you that the file you have is not a tar file ... I'm confused as you are

@mplungjan would ypu please tell me what does dupe mean in this context?yes, now i am getting a tar file, and it contains only one file while i have request a tar with six bands

@JaromandaX no, now i am receiving a tar file not a geotiff, the accepted answer in my previous question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78616054/how-to-get-tar-contents-out-of-a-hexa-representation/78616193?noredirect=1#comment138601597_78616193 helped to debug the code

Oh, so you are no longer receiving a file that begins with 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 13 01 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 01?

@Amr Your two questions are almost identical. I made the comment to stop ppl from closing this question as a duplicate of the other one

@mplungjan i found the solution to my question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78617574/tar-contains-always-the-last-band-request-and-ignores-the-rest  should i delete it or post the answer please

You posted a link to a question - if that is your new question, please delete this question since the other is more elaborate

But this question is different than the one I sent you its link,!!
